What is the purpose of these 10nF capacitors?
What is the purpose of these 10nF capacitors on all the ECU input pins?

Image source: https://www.finjector.com/documents/647ef11579093/TKU-0261230340-.pdf, section 2.4. Error diagnosis

featherbits - Hi, Where did the diagram come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each piece of that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add the source name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, [edit] the question & add a full citation e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). TY

They are for EMI suppression. To keep noise from entering and/or leaving the ECU.
